# Django: the meaning of timeout using Redis as Cache

Tags: python, django, caching, redis, timeout

I am using Django's built-in module with Redis as the cache server. My question is regarding the setting of timeout in the following code:

```
    cache.set(key,value,timeout)
```

Say I set the timeout to be 30s. Does it mean that after 30s the key,value pair in the cache will be deleted and I will have to re-feed the (updated) value to the cache? Something like this:

```
    if cache.get('key') is None:
         cache.set('key','value',30)
    else:
         return cache.get('key')
```

Or after 30s the cache value will still be there?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is given based on the assumption you are using the `django-redis` package, and using the default setup.

> Say I set the timeout to be 30s. Does it mean that after 30s the key,value pair in the cache will be deleted and I will have to re-feed the (updated) value to the cache?

Yes.  The key,value pair will be deleted from redis after the 30s specified as the timeout.  You will then need to repopulate the cache with your given key,value pair again.

The above code that was given in the question to set and get cache keys is valid.  The default value that is returned from `cache.get('key')` is `None` when the key doesn't exist in the redis cache.

Using the `cache.set()` method with a timeout argument, calls the redis command `SETEX`...
http://redis.io/commands/setex

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I have done a bit testing and indeed after 30s it will re-query the database as the data I want no longer exists in the cache.